# Navigation bar title appears with delay in mixed UIKit and SwiftUI project

Tags: swiftui

I'm presenting a SwiftUI view from UIViewController.

```
let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView())
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Title")
    }
}
```

The title appears only after the view has appeared. How to fix?

Answer (score 9):

If you use `UINavigationController` then you need to set the title on the `UIHostingController` for it to appear instantly. Otherwise the navigation title will only appear after the SwiftUI view is rendered.

You can set the navigation title of any `UIViewController` using `title`

```swift
let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView())
vc.title = "Title"
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: It works, but funny that the problem doesn't happen all the time, only on some, seemingly arbitraryly.